# Old cord no red wire, new cord has a red wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

We have 14/3 cord in our house. We bought a new 14/3 cord to connect it together from a outlet to a switched. The 14/3 that's already in our house does not have a red wire. The new one we bought has a red wire. How do we connect when the old one does not have  red wire?

Comment: Cord, or _cable_? Might help if you'd revise to explain what you're doing.

Comment: And what colors _does_ the existing 14/3 have?

Comment: What does the old one have?  Usually can go with black to black, white to white, red to  colour.  An plain outlet usually does not need a xx/3 cable, nor does a plain switch.  More info on what you have is good to put in your question.

Comment: Sorry I meant cable the old cable has colors black, white and ground. The new cable has red, black, white and ground.

Comment: What I was trying to do was use the outlet wire that does not have a red wire connect it to a switch that I'm adding a light under the staircase. So I would need a red wire for the switch right?

Comment: It may be time to take a deep breath and start over. Please [edit] your question to explain your initial goal (adding a switched light by bringing power from an existing outlet?). Include a picture of the power source (the outlet?), then a diagram of the wiring scheme you're planning. Then ask your question for clarification, approval of the process, how to connect what to where, did you buy the right products, etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is a terminology issue. The industry standard nomenclature in the US for NM cable (e.g., Romex) *excludes* the ground wire (bare or green). In other words:

- 14/2 = Black + White + bare ground, 14 AWG
- 14/3 = Black + White + Red + bare ground, 14 AWG

You thought "black + white + ground = 3 wires" and based on printing on the jacket confirmed that it is 14 AWG, so you ordered *14/3*. But what you actually have is *14/2*.

The good news is you wasted a few $ but no harm done. It is perfectly fine to just ignore (or preferably, cap both ends of the red wire with wire nuts, so no loose bits of metal can touch anything). Or return it and buy 14/2. Or buy 14/2 and save this for the next time you wire up a switched circuit that needs the red wire.

There are a number of situations involving switches where you need 3 wires (besides ground). There are also some where you absolutely don't need that red wire (e.g., black & white from existing circuit to switch box, black connected to switch, white connected to white going to light, black going to light connected to the other side of the switch).

Comment: What I was trying to do was use the outlet cable that does not have a red wire to connect it to a switch. I'm trying to add a light fixture under the staircase and is the red wire needed for a switch?

Comment: Black and white connect to black and white at the existing outlet (pigtails or second set of screws), in switch box you have this cable and another black/white going to the light. In the box, whites together, blacks to the two screws on the switch. At the light, black to hot/line, white to neutral.

Comment: You can use black or red wire for the hot(not both in your case).  The one you don't use, use wire nuts on both ends.  It is common to use the black and nut the red, but either one can be use as the hot.  To prevent future confusion, should use the black only.  Red is use for types of circuits(three way switches) that you do not have right now

Comment: Thanks everyone it was very helpful!!